# Having some issues with ProgressDialog. cant make it appear

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

Iam having some problems with the ProgressDialog in android. I thought it would be relatively easy to use but it turns out otherwise LOL. basically i have an Instance of progreesdialog in my activity "RegistrationActivity". I press a button and registration commences by showing a progressdialog when this button is pressed. this is all done on the UI thread.  below is my code which calls my presenter method which in turn calls a method in my mode, as Iam using MVP.

```
@Override
public void registerUser() {

    progdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progdialog.show();

    rpresenter.relayRegisterUser(emailedtxt.getText().toString(),
            passedtxt.getText().toString(), phoneedtxt.getText().toString());

}
```

I have a seperate thread set up in my model. In the model Iam currently faking the registration process by sleeping the thread for five seconds and using a handler to post a value back a value to the UI thread. below is the runnable i create and pass to my thread within the model "RegisterModel".

```
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //upload data to the server
                reghandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progress = 50;
                        regpresenter.updateUIProgress(progress);
                        Log.d("prog updated by :!!", String.valueOf(progress));
                    }
                });


        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        reghandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progress = 100;
                                regpresenter.updateUIProgress(progress);
                                Log.d("prog update 2 :!!", String.valueOf(progress));
                            }
                        });
        appstate.setRegistered(true);
    }
};
```

when i press the button I presumed the progressdialog would appear as it calls the registerUser() method. But it does not. updateUIProgress(progress) call my presenter. This in turn calls a method in my activity/view called UpdateProgress(). to which i post back the value of 100 after the thread in my model has slept for 5 seconds. this method is shown below.

```
@Override
public void updateProgress(int progress) {

    Log.d("increment progactivity:", String.valueOf(progress));
    progdialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

    if(progress == 100)
        hideProgress();
 }
```

Upon recieving the progress value of 100 the "hideProgress()" method is called which is shown below. but as the progressdialog isnt appearing in the first place it doesnt do anything.

```
private void hideProgress()
{
    Log.d("hide prog called", "hide prg called");
    progdialog.dismiss();

}
```

everything to do with the progressdialog is on the UI thread so Iam not too sure what Iam doing wrong here. If anyone out there can help me id appreciate it. Thanks!

EDIT:

forgot to mention I fixed this issue! it was a silly error on my part but i used .join() on the thread which force the UI thread to wait for the registration thread to finish. therefore I was not seeing the progressdialog. oops!

Comment: Create `Handler` and update your `progress` in that..

Comment: reghandler.post() . I create reghandler on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

In another cases you should post UI updates into UIThread. See [that](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Comment: my handler is created on the UI thread and I post runnables to that. thought that was okay. tbh id prefer to not use AsyncTask if i can do it with a thread.

Comment: I post UI updates on the UI thread using "reghandler,post()" as shown above. Id prefer not to use AsyncTask in this case if i can just do it with a thread.

Comment: i create it in my constructor.  reghandler = new Handler(); which is on the UI thread.

Comment: Can you explain me...
Your problem in case: "progress not updated" or "updates without 5 sec delay "? Or something else? Sorry but I bad understand a problem ))

Comment: basically the progress dialog doesnt even appear when I press the button. I have in the button method Thread.start(); It just doesnt appear.

Comment: the progdialog doesnt appear when i press the button. thread runs fine. calling methods on progdialog dont seem to have any effect

Comment: Is your problem was solved? IF no, maybe you push little demo with all infrastructure classes(only needed methods) on github and I can pull it and check? It can be many problems and I cant guess ))

Comment: basically Instantiating and calling methods on progress dialog are my issues. thread runs fine. all methods called on the progressdialog are called in the same activity. for example. progdialog.show() doesnt make the progress dialog appear.

Comment: ill recreate what i did in a sized down version of my app and post the link. Iam trying to use the MVP pattern too seperate out the logic. for my sins. LOL

Comment: https://github.com/eoinahern/IM_App_prototype/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/eoin_a/im_app20/Views/RegistrationActivity.java  heres my main activity. Its a bit untidy at present.  also here is where iam running the seperate thread. https://github.com/eoinahern/IM_App_prototype/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/eoin_a/im_app20/Models/RegisterModel.java

Comment: guess iam just going to have to read back over the docs on dialogs as Iam very much stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Use Async Task

Try something like this..

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type:
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

class UpdateProgressbar extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {  

    // Show Progress Bar Dialog
    Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);

        publishProgress("0");

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... result) {

        try {       

            //your code
            //.........
            //.........


            publishProgress(""+(int)((count*100)/lenghtOfFile)); //update progress bar  

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Update progress bar

   protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));

   }


     //Close the progress dialog

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // dismiss the dialog
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    }

}
```

Comment: can it be done without AsyncTask??  ill use it if necessary but id prefer to just use Threads.

Comment: AsyncTask can be used only if background task is simple(not long). You can use an Executors (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)

Comment: registering the device could take a while so Iam opting to use threads.